# react navigation variable navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a flatlist and 5 items I want every item to navigate different pages
but currently it gives me an error

```
 <FlatList style={{backgroundColor:'#ffffff'}}
    data={[{key: 'Book',details:'sssss',icon:'ios-calendar-outline',way:'Home'}]}
        renderItem={({item}) => <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => navigate({item.way})}>
```

how can I pass {item.way} variable into navigate()

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => navigate({item.way})}> why this not working gives unexpected .

Comment: @dsdsa Because that's shorthand object properties. It's the same as `navigate({ item.way: item.way })` which is a syntax error. A key with non-valid identifier symbols must have itself wrapped in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error here `navigate({item.way})`. Try:

```
navigate(item.way)
```

Comment: thnaks!/////////